# Is created_at in Rails by default Time.now.utc.to_date?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When `Rails` creates an active record and inserts it, is the `created_at` value *practically* the same as `Time.now.utc.to_date`?

Comment: "Practically the same" depends on usage. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Also, did you mean `to_datetime`? `to_date` will drop the time portion.

Answer (score 2):

In most cases yes, but it depends on the default timezone configuration option.

[`ActiveRecord::Timestamp`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/timestamp.rb#L83-L85)  code:

```
def current_time_from_proper_timezone
  default_timezone == :utc ? Time.now.utc : Time.now
end
```

You can [change](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Timestamp.html) timezone setting in:

```
config.active_record.time_zone_aware_attributes = false
```

Answer (score 0):

If you meant `to_date`, then no, in the worst case it could be nearly 24 hours off.

If you meant `to_datetime`, then I believe it will be the same to the second. But note that if you call `Time.now` immediately before or after creating a record it may not match to the second. I'm curious to know why you need to convert to a `DateTime` though.

Just test it yourself (let's say your AR class is `Post`):

```
dtm_before = Time.now.to_datetime
post = Post.create!(attributes)
dtm_after = Time.now.to_datetime  # zone does not matter!
# these differences should be tiny
dtm_before.to_time - post.created_at
dtm_after.to_time - post.created_at
```

I said the zone doesn't matter because when you're doing time arithmetic, zones are automatically taken into account. Example:

```
# let's assume your local TZ-offset isn't zero
t = Time.now
t == t.getutc   # true
t - t.getutc  # 0.0 (these are the exact same instant)
```